# Activate function for each instance of class at random time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 different tags containing images that blink their eyes. I have a script that does this, but they all blink at the same time, which unfortunately is noticeable.

Is there any way that I can attribute the function I have to each different target (class="blink"), but with a random delay so the blink rate of each image seems natural?

Here's the function:

```
var blink = function(){
  $('.blink img + img').toggle();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.blink img + img').toggle();
  }, 50);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ranNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200) + 2000;
  setInterval(blink, ranNum);
});
```

If anybody can offer some advice then thank you in advance! (apparently I'm not allowed to in responses)

Answer (score 3):

You're not specifying which you want to blink.  Untested, but this will get you on the right track:

```
$(function () {
    $('.blink img + img').each(function (key, el) {
        setInterval(function () {
            $(el).hide(0).delay(100).show(0);
        }, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200) + 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Although it’s on the right track, the interval will be the same for each blink, even if it’s random at first.

Comment: @David What makes you say that?  I think you're misinterpreting the 100ms timeout in blink, which simply re-opens the eye.

Comment: I’m saying that the delay between each "blink" will be the same, since you are using setInterval.

Comment: @David The blink rate for each eye will be consistent, yes, but they will all be random relative to each other.